# Images not loading when using jQuery .html apending

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Me and the team have been a bit stumped on this so I'm hoping someone has come across this problem before.

I have a notification div that flies in depending on some event calls. The script I have seems to be working everywhere except one application where the images won't load. Both the icon css background image and the actual loading indicator won't show if the container is dynamically appended.

If i remove the initial `display:none` property the images load, but once the trigger is called they don't.

Unfortunately the application is on an internal network and I can't share a link, but I've included a screen shot and a jsfiddle to the code I'm using. (which in it's self is doing exactly what it's supposed to)

http://jsfiddle.net/FSshV/7/

It's a heavy js based app with some ASP.NET 2.0 here and there and some ajax calls bouncing around but doesn't seem to be giving any errors and i haven't been able to pinpoint the problem.

I know it's a long shot and not much to go on but maybe someone hit that wall before :)

I'm curious if anyone has seen a similar problem before and can share some insight?

PS: yes I've checked if the image paths are correct, and they are ^.^

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it working in the fiddle for you... it is working for me

Comment: also can you check the developer tools -> network tab and see whether the image request is sent by the browser is so what is its status

Comment: What does the inspector say after it appends for the img src?

Comment: if it works well elsewhere...almost sounds like a css issue. What clues do you get from live html?

Comment: Edited the post with another screenshot.
Debugger doesn't give any useful information. The 2 resources indicated as missing are not relative(always missing in dev box). 

As you can see if I hover/click on the image source from the generated HTML I can see the image. As far as I can tell the styles are quite simple and proper.

Comment: And yes this works in jsfiddle or anywhere else besides this one application. I just thought maybe someone has run into this type of issue before so I can maybe narrow down where the problem might be coming from.